# How do I make all python imports/errors visible?

Tags: python, django, python-2.7

Got one of those lovely django errors

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:
app.company: 'fields' has an m2m relation with model <class 'viewer.models.ParserField'>, which has either not been installed or is abstract.
```

This is happening when I try to run some of my unit tests...  `manage shell` import the various pieces seems to be working fine, I can fix it if I can just find it....

Trying to figure out at which point the error is happening, but django's lovely import error exception handler is making it very difficult.

Is there a way to monkey patch importing and exceptions so I can watch what is happening? `python -v` isn't helping because it doesn't give me the errors and error handling going on.

Answer (score 1):

From `manage.py --help`:

```
  --traceback           Print traceback on exception
```

But I would try adding the app containing `viewer.models.ParserField` to `settings.INSTALLED_APPS`.

Comment: viewer has been in installed apps for more than a year.  There are no easily visible syntax errors (piecemeal imports work)...  In fact `manage shell` and `manage runserver` both work....

Comment: --traceback just gives me the traceback for the reporting location, django's magic import stuff is masking this one.

Comment: Then that's where you need to start looking. It will take some work, but I'm sure you'll find it.

Comment: I did solve it, but I didn't find it.  At some point, it started working, I still am trying to figure out how to solve this rather common Django issue.